# how to put link in css button and still i want to see my transition effects of button before to proceed next page?

Tags: jquery, html, css, css-transitions

how to add link in this css button without damaging the transition effects?
heres sample i got in google 
Visit
http://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_buttons_animate2

Answer (score 1):

Try this using setTimeout():

```js
$(function() {
  $('a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    setTimeout(function() {
      window.location = $(this).attr('href')
    }, 200);
  });
});
```

```css
.button {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  border: none;
  font-size: 28px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 200px;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.4s;
  /* Safari */
  transition-duration: 0.4s;
  text-decoration: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.button:after {
  content: "";
  background: #90EE90;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  padding-top: 300%;
  padding-left: 350%;
  margin-left: -20px!important;
  margin-top: -120%;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.8s
}
.button:active:after {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: 0s
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="http://google.ro">
  <button class="button">Click Me</button>
</a>
```

Comment: is this correct
<style>
$('a').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  setTimeout(function() {
    window.location = $(this).attr('href')
  }, 200);
})
</style>

Comment: <style>
.button {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  border: none;
  font-size: 28px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 200px;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.4s;
  /* Safari */
  transition-duration: 0.4s;
  text-decoration: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
}

Comment: .button:after {
  content: "";
  background: #90EE90;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  padding-top: 300%;
  padding-left: 350%;
  margin-left: -20px!important;
  margin-top: -120%;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.8s
}
.button:active:after {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: 0s
}
</style>

Comment: first comment change the style tag to a script tag lol and apend a document ready function to it,do you even know html?

Comment: i know how to use HTML>

Comment: but i doesnt work for me... but in your sample it works

Comment: from a scale from 1 to 100 how much html do you know?

Comment: 5 ...please teach me how to do that beacause that is my problem how to put link in css buttton without damaging the transition effects...i already copy your codes in my website but still doesnt work the effects for me

Answer (score 0):

You can use setTimeout() for doing things like this.

```
onclick="setTimeout(function(){window.open('http://www.google.com')},500)
```

Just put the transition duration instead of '500' in the code above.

Comment: @KennyTan <button class="button" onclick="setTimeout(function(){window.open('http://naver.com')},500)">Click Me</button>

Comment: another thing how to prevent if i click the button it creates new tab in my browser?

Comment: @KennyTan <button class="button" onclick="setTimeout(function(){window.open('naver.com', '_self')},500)">Click Me</button>

Comment: is this correct @lnpyo Jeon
<button class="button" onclick="setTimeout(function(){window.open('sample.html'; ,'_self)},500)">Click Me</button>

Comment: @KennyTan delete the semicolon (;) after 'sample.html'

Comment: but nothing happen when i use this code the link in button doesnt work know
<button class="button" onclick="setTimeout(function(){window.open('sample.html' ,'_self)},500)">Click Me</button>

Comment: but the transition is still moving

Comment: @KennyTan I'm sorry but there's nothing wrong in the code... You might want to check the url first. If the problem keep happens, post the whole codes.

Comment: heres the code @lnpyo Jeon https://anotepad.com/notes/jnic4w

Comment: my (sample.html) is done so i link this to my hover button

Comment: @KennyTan Replace (<div class="ripple"><button class="button" onclick="setTimeout(function()window.open('sample.html'self)},500)">Click Me</button>) to (<div class="ripple"><button class="button" onclick="setTimeout(function(){window.open('sample.html', '_self')},500)">Click Me</button></div>)

Comment: @KennyTan I replaced ('sample.html'self) to ('sample.html', '_self') and added </div> at the end of body and it works just fine.

Comment: ow it WORKS for me! thank you for your time to able to help me :)

Comment: @KennyTan Anytime :)

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the buttom in an `<a>` tag and add an href to it, which refers to your link.

Answer (score 0):

Use the onclick function to your button tag. For example:

```
<button class="button" onclick="location.href='http://google.com';">Click Me</button>
```

It will not hamper the transition effects of that button.